# Javascript keeps creating duplicate records

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I have a csv that I have to read in and have to upload to a MySql database using Prisma. However... Writing all the students to the database works but the entire 'if a group exists, use that group and if it doesn't exist, create it' part doesn't work because he keeps adding duplicate groups into the database, I have tried so many options by now and none seem to work and I'm getting desperate...

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  fs.createReadStream("./Upload/StudentenEnGroepen001.csv")
  .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 2 }))
  .on("data", async (row) => {
    let group = null;
    let inschrijving = row[6];
    if (inschrijving === "Student") {
      let parts = row[8].split(",");
      let groep = parts[1];
      let groepNaam = groep.split(" - ")[0].trim();
      const student = await prisma.student.create({
        data: {
            Code: row[0],
            Gebruikersnaam: row[1],
            Familienaam: row[2],
            Voornaam: row[3],
            Sorteernaam: row[4],
            Email: row[5],
        },
      })
      const groupCount = await prisma.groep.count({
        where: {
            Naam: { equals: groepNaam },
        }
      });
      if (groupCount > 0) {
        const existingGroup = await prisma.groep.findFirst({
            where: {
                Naam: { equals: groepNaam },
            }
        });
        group = existingGroup;
      } else {
        group = await prisma.groep.create({
            data: {
                Naam: groepNaam,
            }
        });
      }        
      await prisma.groepstudent.create({
        data: {
          GroepID: group.ID,
          StudentID: student.ID,
        },
      });
      }
  })
  res.json({message: "Studenten en groepen zijn toegevoegd."});
});
```

My latest attempt was this but this also doesn't work.

```
        const groupCount = await prisma.groep.count({
            where: {
              Naam: { equals: groepNaam },
            }
          });
          if (groupCount > 0) {
            const existingGroup = await prisma.groep.findFirst({
              where: {
                Naam: { equals: groepNaam },
              }
            });
            group = existingGroup;
          } else {

            group = await prisma.groep.create({
              data: {
                Naam: groepNaam,
              }
            });
          }
```

I tried to just use 'findFirst' but that also didn't work...

```
group = await prisma.groep.findFirst({
            where: {
              Naam: { equals: groepNaam },
            }
          });
if (group) {
// then use this group
else{
// create group..
...
```

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? What are those queries returning?

Comment: As far as I have just debugged groupCount is never even assigned

Comment: the name of the model and the column name are correct though

Comment: So if you `console.log("group count is " + groupCount)` after the `await` for the query and *before* the `if` statement, you get nothing? Well if so that would certainly explain why the `if` is failing. Probably you should first figure out how to get those queries to work.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please include the errors you're getting?

Adding to what Pointy said, try going back to the point where your app was actually working. Then, start adding in small pieces at a time. Run your app each time to see when it bombs out on you. Check your debugger for clues as to when exactly this is happening. These errors should point you in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: I don't get any errors, he runs the entire code 'successfully' but I don't want duplicate records of 'group' in the database

Comment: Okay, are you able to comment out all the code other than the existingGroup conditional"? I would guess you're getting duplicate records because your conditional is returning null or false instead of true, even when there's an existing group in the db. 

So if you can put a breakpoint on the existingGroup conditional and then see what the result of that conditional is. Maybe this conditional isn't working properly.